# FOSElasticaBundle config.yml reuse persistence

Tags: elasticsearch, symfony, foselasticabundle

I have the following in my config.yml:

```
# other settings...

fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        homestead:
            types:
                volunteer:
                    mappings:
                        firstName: ~
                        lastName: ~
                        username: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\Volunteer
                        provider: ~
                        listener:
                            immediate: ~
                            logger: true
                        finder: ~
                        elastica_to_model_transformer:
                            ignore_missing: true
# more other settings...
```

I was wondering how I can predefine the persistence so I can reuse it instead of adding it to every entity.

Secondly I was wondering how I can put it in a different file altogether